# Find the even or odd of decimal number from uniform distribution in R?

Tags: r, uniform

It is clear that `runif()` command in R with create random numbers with uniform distribution. Assuming I want to create 100 random variables of uniform distribution with min=0 and max=1, there will give you 100 decimal numeric numbers. Is there any way to count how much of these decimal numbers are odds and even in R? By default, I know there is a way for integer numbers to count even or odd numbers by R.

Comment: Only integers can be even or odd?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume for the moment that you mean to ask what the 16 digit to the right of the decimal place of runif(1) might be. Why do I choose the 16th digit? Because that's the limit of machine precision for R floating point arithmetic:

```
 .Machine$double.eps
[1] 2.220446e-16
```

Just divide by the results of runif(.) by that number and deliver in a character representation:

```
> as.character( print(runif(1) * 1/.Machine$double.eps, signif=16) )
[1] 3.488493e+15
[1] "3488493498007552"
```

This will give you the 16th digit of such a number:

```
> strsplit( as.character( print(runif(1) * 1/.Machine$double.eps, signif=16) ),"")[[1]][16]
[1] 3.742119e+15
[1] "0"
```

I suspect there is something about this process that I don't entirely understand because I get half of the results as `NA` when I'm at the 16th digit:

```
> table(sapply( sapply( as.character(myrunif * 1/.Machine$double.eps, signif=16) , strsplit, split=""), "[", 15) )

 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 
14  6 10  9 12  7 22  5  8  4 
> table(sapply( sapply( as.character(myrunif * 1/.Machine$double.eps, signif=16) , strsplit, split=""), "[", 16) )

 0  2  4  6  8 
19 16 19 15 10
```

Makes me wonder if your professor of mathematics assigned this question to get you to this point?

Comment: It seems that my question was not clear. for example, if the uniform distribution from (0,1) gives us these numbers: 0.45,0.56,0.36,0.95. How could I say that 0.45 and 0.95 is odd, 0.56 and 0.36 are even? is there anyway for it?

Comment: So you just want the second digit to define odd/evenness. The modification of my code would simple be to multiply by 100 and take the last digit of the character representation of `round(x, 0)`.